# How to automatically delete old completed orders in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to set up Woocommerce to automatically clean up old completed orders. Moving to trash would be OK, but I would really prefer to have them deleted. Here's what I'm using now, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
function expire_after_x_days(){
        global $wpdb;
    // Get current time
        $today = date("mdy");

    // set time to expire
        $time_to_expire = "-180 days";
        $expiration_date = date("mdy", strtotime( $today . $time_to_expire));

    // Get orders with processing status
        $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_order' AND post_status = 'wc-completed'");

        if( !empty($result)) foreach ($result as $order){
            // Get order's time
            $order_time = get_the_time('mdy', $order->ID );

    // Compare order's time with current time -10 days
        if ( $order_time < $expiration_date ){

    // Update order status    
               wp_delete_post($order_id,true);
            }
        }
} 

    // Use the best HOOK for your case 
    add_action( 'admin_footer', 'expire_after_x_days' );

    // OR simply call the function if you are pasting this in your functions.php
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
function expire_after_x_days(){
        global $wpdb;
    // Get current time
        $today = date("mdy");

    // set time to expire
        $time_to_expire = "-180 days";
        $expiration_date = date("mdy", strtotime( $today . $time_to_expire));

    // Get orders with processing status
        $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_order' AND post_status = 'wc-completed'");

        if( !empty($result)) foreach ($result as $order){
            // Get order's time
            $order_time = get_the_time('mdy', $order->ID );

    // Compare order's time with current time -10 days
        if ( $order_time < $expiration_date ){

    // Update order status    
               wp_delete_post($order_id,true);
            }
        }
} 

    // Use the best HOOK for your case 
    add_action( 'admin_footer', 'expire_after_x_days' );

    // OR simply call the function if you are pasting this in your functions.php
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean? Are you getting an error?

Comment: You should maybe change `$order_id` to `$order->ID`. The former is undefined…

Comment: May I suggest that you set error reporting at the first line of you php file. That would probably have pointed you to this error. This is the line you need to add: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: To be absolutely sure you see the errors, also add this line: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use instead the following that will trash and delete all old completed orders *(older than 180 days)*, by batch of 200 to avoid crashing your website. No need to use any WordPress scheduled actions that are really not reliable.

Here is a simplified and improved code version:

```php
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'auto_trash_old_completed_orders' );
function auto_trash_old_completed_orders(){
    $completed_order_ids = wc_get_orders( array(
        'limit'         => 200, // By batch of 200 orders
        'status'        => 'completed', 
        'return'        => 'ids',
        'date_created'  => '<' . date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-6 months")),
    ) );

    if ( count($completed_order_ids) > 0 ){
        foreach($completed_order_ids as $completed_order_id ) {
            wp_trash_post($completed_order_id); //
            wp_delete_post($completed_order_id, true);
        }
    }
}
```

It should work.

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting this error:

Syntax error, unexpected ''date_created'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'.

Comment: Sorry a typo… I have updated the code… It should work now.

Comment: Well something's not right because that deleted all my completed orders.

Comment: Oups my fault… I have updated and tested the order query, now it works.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened. We had over 2,000 completed orders, many of them from within the last week, and now they are all gone. It's ok since we have confirmation emails and a synced quickbooks file if we need to reference anything. But I would like to get this working at 180 days if possible.

Comment: To help me learn, can you tell me where the mistake was?

Comment: "-6 months" yes, but not "-180 days"… You should always make a backup before. Anyway I am very sorry again.

Comment: It's ok. We almost never reference the completed orders, and we have paper copies of everything. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the code you've provided:

You've duplicated the `expire_after_x_days()` function. This will cause a fatal error in PHP.

The date format `mdy` is not an ideal choice for date comparisons. You should use a format that provides a more natural order, such as `Ymd`.

You are using `get_the_time('mdy', $order->ID)` to fetch the date. Instead, you should use `get_post_time()`.

`$order_id` is not defined. It should be `$order->ID`.

Hooking this function to `admin_footer` is not an ideal choice. Every time an admin page is loaded, you'll be querying and potentially deleting old orders. A scheduled event or a cron job is a better fit.

Using SQL directly can be risky, especially for important tasks. WooCommerce provides a way to query orders that should be preferred over direct SQL whenever possible.

```php
function expire_after_x_days(){
    global $wpdb;

    // Get current time
    $today = date("Ymd");

    // Set time to expire
    $time_to_expire = "-180 days";
    $expiration_date = date("Ymd", strtotime($time_to_expire));

    // Query WooCommerce orders using WC_Order_Query
    $args = array(
        'status' => 'completed',
        'date_before' => $expiration_date,
        'return' => 'ids',  // Only return IDs
    );
    
    $orders = wc_get_orders($args);

    foreach ($orders as $order_id){
        wp_delete_post($order_id, true);
    }
} 

// Schedule this event using WP Cron for regular cleanup. 
if (! wp_next_scheduled ( 'expire_after_x_days' )) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'expire_after_x_days');
}
```

This function makes use of the `wc_get_orders()` function from WooCommerce to fetch old completed orders. The function is then scheduled to run daily using WP Cron.

Comment: Thank you! I inserted your code and saved the snippet. Do I need to make any specific changes, like adding a value to time()? Sorry I'm pretty new at this.